# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Field`. after installing mui v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form, react-forwardref

Migrating to Material ui v4 and got this error

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Field`.
> in Field (created by TextField)

Which points to the redux form field component

```
export const TextField = props => (
    <Field
        component={renderTextField}
        {...props}
    />
);
```

I believe it has to do with React.forwardRef when looking at the [docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/)

**Tried**

1.)

Redux form points to `forwardRef : boolean [optional]`  when added, the issue persits

```
 <Field
     component={renderTextField}
     forwardRef={true}
     {...props}
  />
```

2.)

`component= {React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <renderTextField innerRef={ref} {...props} />)}`

which is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the "latest" redux form package, the one which has `React.forwardRef` implementation.

Install 8+

```
"redux-form": "^8.3.6"
```